# Subscript out of bounds error due to passing mutate (dplyr) a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I need to apply a rolling function to a large dataset, but it needs to apply to grouped windows specified in `group_by` . Passing the function to `mutate` returns a "subscript out of bounds" error on *some* subsets of the data but works on others. I can't provide my data as it is confidential but I found a similar enough reproducible example.

I have tried tracing the error which led me to believe it is due to the function returning a matrix data type (1d). Coercing it to dataframe or vector did not work.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(caTools)

# Works
i <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species)%>% 
  arrange(Sepal.Length,.by_group=T)%>%
  mutate(q_low = runquantile(lag(Sepal.Length),3,probs=0.2,endrule = 'NA',align='right'))

# Gives error 
# Grouping by and arranging by more than one variable
m <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl,gear)%>% 
  arrange(gear,.by_group=T)%>%
  mutate(q_low = runquantile(lag(drat),3,probs=0.2,endrule = 'NA',align='right'))
#> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, (k2 + 1):n, , value = y[1:(n - k2), ]): subscript out of bounds
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Expected a similar result to the Iris example with the function being applied to the grouping and the NA's in the right spot. In actuality I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first example, all the groups have number of rows equal to 50, but in second case, it is not true, some of them are having number of rows as 1.

```
runquantile(rnorm(4), 3, probs =0.2, endrule = 'NA',align='right')
#[1]         NA         NA -0.5466295 -0.4099716
```

Above works, but if the number of elements is less than 'k'

```
runquantile(rnorm(1), 3, probs =0.2, endrule = 'NA',align='right')
```

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, (k2 + 1):n, , value = y[1:(n - k2), ]) :
>   subscript out of bounds

---

We need to take care of those cases with a `if/else` condition

```
library(dplyr)
library(caTools)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl,gear)%>% 
  arrange(gear,.by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(q_low = if(n() < 3) NA_real_ else 
      runquantile(lag(drat),3,probs=0.2,endrule = 'NA',align='right'))
```

Comment: thanks for your response! real data set has groups of unequal lengths. when i implemented your fix i got all NAs ... my problem is that sometimes it works and sometimes it gives an error. no reason as to why. when i passed it to %>%data.frame() %>% right before mutate, it works but then does not preserve grouping

Comment: @sg15  I was able to reproduce the same error you showed with the example.  In your real data, I am not sure as it is not showed, but the unequal lengths are reproduced in `mtcars` as well

Comment: i reworked my grouping a bit and your solution worked. thank you so much!!